# Struts 1 to Spring migration, Loading of all the properties file at the startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, struts1

I have following flow in struts application for property file reading-

- entry in `web.xml` with init params containing the name of properties file.
- then, with the help of `context.getInitParams()` reading the data.

How  can I perform the same in spring 3 and spring boot?

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot, you can use a argument called spring.config.location when you run the application to specify which files you want to use as properties files.

Comment: ,Can you please give me the implementation, I  am unable to get anything and also I am new ...